# What are the minimum historical changes that would permit the use of paratroopers at the beginning of World War I?

Tags: science-based, warfare, alternate-history

What are the minimum historical changes that would permit the use of paratroopers at the beginning of World War I, so that they accomplish the following requisites:

1. It should be maintained a heavy protected secret of state.
2. Be useful.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130824/discussion-on-question-by-erdel-von-mises-what-are-the-minimum-historical-change).

Comment: I doubt taking over the Parliament (French or British) would have meant instant defeat.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi why?

Comment: @ErdelvonMises Governments are not their country's general populations, nor even the leaders of their military forces in the field. Countries do not surrender because you kill or capture their leadership.

Comment: @Ash The population make sense, but the millitary is under the charge of the supreme general (the president).

Comment: @ErdelvonMises No they're not, the military as a whole may be under political control but in the field soldiers are under the command of their unit officers and you can't kill enough of them fast enough for them not to mount an overwhelming defense on their home soil.

Comment: And the field officers are under control of other officers that are under control of generals, and so on, until you get to the president.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises All officers are fully capable of taking higher command when necessary or acting independently in light of conditions on the ground when no orders are forthcoming from their immediate superiors, this was more true during WWI than it is in many modern militaries. Due to the lack of communications capabilities field commanders during WWI had to be capable of responding to whatever situation they were faced with and were trained accordingly.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises Signing an act of capitulation is not under a single entity control, usually the chief of the state (monarch or president) is required and only after consultation with both the executive (govt) and legislative (parliament) powers. You'd need to capture all of them in the same time and _usually_ they aren't in the same place. This letting aside the population may not like the thing at all (happened [starting last year with Armenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020%E2%80%932021_Armenian_protests)) and are likely to take the matter in their own hands.

Comment: @Ash Until 1939, the Army was always very vertical command, there were just listen and obey trainings. Also, what if the peace treatry as generous, like you par just 500 000 Franks, and join the Zollverin, and you are now my friend.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi But if the proposal is generous, like just paid a minor war taxes, but you join the Zollverin, and now are my friend?

Comment: @Ash If they join the Zollverin, the peace is prettry much guarented, because for the time that the demagogo, gets to the power the industry is no co-dependent with Germany, so War is to expesnive to even think about.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises You seem to have made some assumptions and be certain of some ideas that fly in the face of both human nature and real world history, while that is the case further discussion would seem completely pointless.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises it doesn't matter the offer, especially in the beginning of a war the population doesn't feel the "need to be treated better or have a friendship with you, the burglar that just broke into my house". It take years of grinding in wars to reach of "Well, we tried our best, but we can't continue like that". Besides, early 1900, the two countries that you mentioned just finished smothering the Ottoman empire, were big colonial powers and the nationalism spirit was strong enough to preclude such a reaction.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Okey, then march like (when mustache weird invaded Denmark), using parachutes to sabotage, etc. So they were unable to mantain the frontline.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises so? Britain did exactly that in WWII and stiffened its upper lip and went ahead with it even after the France capitulated and before the Americans joined to help. What makes you think starting from way better position, against a puny invasion of under 10,000 people, they'd be cowering in fear?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I think you do no understand what I mean to say. I say that use the parachutes to be able to advance sabotaging supply lines, etc. So they can't mantain the trench warfare and the German army can advance.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises well, yes, of course. Isn't this the role of paratroopers? But it's not like the use of them automatically wins a war. The Talibans resisted in a war against practically anyone else (who could send paratroopers anywhere anytime) for the last 20 years.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Yes, they resisted, because guerrilla warfare is unwinable unless you are willing to kill civilians as nothing.

Comment: Russia was willing to kill civilians as nothing in Afghanistan (explosives planted in children's toys), but that got them nowhere.

Comment: How can asking for the minimum number of changes to create a historical divergence be opinion-based? We've answered a lot of questions like this over the years. At worst, the OP may be missing details about the expected end result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Under No Circumstances Short of Nuclear War**

Sparknotes: Any handwavium that would grant the ability for german troops to secure Paris/London such that they capture enough of those governments to effect a surrender and hold long enough to make that surrender possible would be such that Germany'd be so technologically ahead of the other great powers as to win the war waaay more believably via other methods.

There are a couple insurmountable problems.  The first is that aircraft are in their infancy to the point where, in 1914, NOBODY ON EARTH knew how to survive an aircraft going into a spin.  (which is now a basic skill for all people learning to fly)  The aircraft themselves were glorified motorized kites that were still decades of aerodynamics, engineering, and tooling advances away from being useful as paratroop transports. [For details see Marked for Death](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/marked-for-death-james-hamilton-paterson/1123899790) So much so that if you got those advances handwaved the nation which had them would be so far ahead of their enemies in other facets that it makes the whole thing ridiculous.  Which leaves Zeppelins.

German Zeppelins are essentially invulnerable to enemy fire in 1914.  They can go too high for antiaircraft guns, planes are unarmed, and even armed planes cannot rise high enough to shoot at them.  Their cargo capacity it limited, and they're fairly slow.  Another answer's ballpark that each could hold 90 paratroopers is probably generous, as they would also need to carry some form of radio/extra supplies to actually communicate to their politicians in Berlin that they'd succeeded/when to get help etc.  I would say 75 men per zeppelin.  But that doesn't really matter since we're going to grant the germans 200 zeppelins for the attack.  Which you'd need to increase German textile, zinc, and engine manufacture to work.  We'll assume that the High Seas Fleet is responsible for them, and you're basically swapping destroyers and other light surface ships for zeppelins. It's obviously not that simple, but the Germans decided on this plan in at least 1900 to get the zeppelins built and troops trained, so we'll assume they shifted resources around such that they can field 200 zeppelins without taking critical resources away from the army.

So now we have 15,000 men set to rain down on London.  We are NOT going to rain down on Paris because 15,000 people (assuming 100% get there, and they won't) is trivial for the French garrisons in/around Paris to wreck.  Remember in WWI there are mass call-ups BEFORE the war starts.  The Paris depots are full of men.  and by "full" I mean "hundreds of thousands."  Your paratroopers would have no chance.  Given the way french infantry fought in 1914 I wouldn't be certain a modern airborne division, without vehicles, could take and hold the city unsupported.

Against London... well still no chance. Because your 15,000 troops (which, again, are carried by 200 almost-certainly-would-need-divine-intervention-to-create zeppelins) equate to one division.  The brits, ALSO gathering troops before the war, likely have multiple divisions in/around London.  These are all good, professional troops.  Arguably the best in the world.  So even though your 15k paratroopers are germany's best and bravest, they're likely "par" to the brits.  Only without any artillery.  Maybe more machineguns but certainly less ammunition.  ("more" here being unimpressive.  The whole division might have 20 machineguns, and that's assuming they were brought at all!  In 1914 nobody was quite sure of the things.)  Then they drop.  Only they can't drop in London because landing over a city is a death sentence to men in parachutes with even WWII-levels of control.  So they land outside. and gather, and strike... at a city defended by multiple divisions.  Plus they'd have to be resupplied with ammunition at least (1914 armies were less picky about living off the civilians than we are) via airship.  But we know you can't reliably air-supply a division even with WWII era tech.  So even IF they take the city they'd likely hold it for less than a week, all the whole british (and french) reinforcements would be desperate to re-take the city.  So even if you captured the king and all of parliment they'd likely just sit smugly for a week until the german division surrendered.

The logistics of the thing are patently impossible.  You'd do better with a zepplin-dropped company doing suicide strikes against Allied Corps/Army HQs.  They probably wouldn't do something like "Kill all the french army commanders" but if they caused enough chaos in the communications they'd de-stablize coordination across the whole front, which would probably be enough to tip the scales to germany taking paris and driving the BEF into a pocket they couldn't get out of.  That'd end the war in the west in 6-8 weeks, which is the best you can hope for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you could land your division in the palace of westminister you still lose, because taking parliament and the king won't work. You won't win the war, you will only take away your opponent's ability to surrender. Take the king and wrath shall boil over.

Answer (score 18):

No realistic paratroop force could take over London or Paris, then or now.

In your time frame, you simply don't have the industrial capacity.  Germany only had 15 Zeppelins at the start of WWI.  Despite their large size, they had a fairly small payload - 9100 kg for the M class.  Figure 100 kg per paratrooper (including equipment), that's 90 troops on the ground per airship.  Even 100 airships could only deliver 9000 troops.  In London, they'd be outnumbered by just the 16,000 police officers.

Second reason why paratroopers alone are not a practical invasion force is simple logistics.  As an advance force, taking the target by surprise, sure.  But once they're on the ground, those paratroops will need a constant supply of food, ammunition, and other supplies.  In the case of Paris, you'd have to bring them across country, where their advance would probably be stopped, just as the German advance was in WWI.  For London, you also have to get the supplies across the English Channel, despite the opposition of the British Navy.

Responding to some of the questions raised in comments.

1. Dropping the paratroops on Parliment isn't going to work. Even if it happens to be in session (I assume you have good intelligence), and technically surrender at gunpoint, that "surrender" isn't going to be accepted by the rest of the country.  (Compare to Trump's January 6th coup attempt, and the fact that US military commanders were making plans to resist such a coup: https://www.cnn.com/2021/07/14/politics/donald-trump-election-coup-new-book-excerpt/index.html )
2. I quoted the number of police in London just as a size comparison.  Britain also had a sizeable army, with units probably based not to far from London, but I don't know where to find figures for that era.  Also, this was before the British had gotten nearly as far with disarming the public.  London had about 7 million people at that time.  Assuming less than 1% had a gun easily to hand, they still outnumber the paratroops by a factor of 10.
3. Resupplying by air doesn't work.  Airships, and particularly ones using hydrogen as a lifting gas, are big fat targets for airplanes.  2/3 of the Zeppelins used to bomb London in WWI were shot down: https://www.history.com/news/londons-world-war-i-zeppelin-terror

Furthermore, while you can drop bombs anywhere in a city and get some result, to resupply your paratroops, you have to drop precisely where those troops happen to be.  That means you have to fly during the day, making your airships even better targets than they would be at night.

Comment: Why do you think that the police force would be able to flight professional soldiers trained for war?

Comment: And why the Zeppelins/Airships cannot do also the job to drop the supplies?

Comment: @ErdelvonMises I wouldn't care to put any bets on it myself. The paratroops are better trained, but they aren't better armed (not if they're going to fit into the weight limit of their chutes) and they don't know the city like the locals do; the locals are also probably much better coordinated. (Remember, radios in this era are heavy and delicate; they aren't really airdrop-friendly.) But the police are just going to be the *start* of their troubles. A mass airdrop from a huge fleet of zeppelins is going to attract the attention of army regulars almost instantly. And then artillery...

Comment: @Cadence As said in the other section. No if the parliment surrender first. and they have at least one machine gun

Comment: After this whole Brexit fiasco, I'm not sure the British Parliament could quickly come to a decision even if you literally waved a gun in their faces.

Comment: I apologize for suggesting this James, but this might not have been an answer to the question in any of its revisions. I could believe some version of the question, "could paratroopers make the difference?" would be an appropriate frame challenge. Was that what you intended?

Comment: @ErdelvonMises During WW2 Hitler thought he could keep the 6th Army in Stalingrad resupplied purely through the air. We all know how that turned out.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises I wouldn't bet on 90,000 paratroopers versus the population of Whitechapel in a bad mood let alone 9000 against greater London, without the fact that many of the people on the street are going to be soldiers, former or current.

Comment: @Ash then parachute over the parliment.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises Have a look at how hopelessly scattered the paratroopers in operations during WWII got on deployment, now increase by an order of magnitude for each of: using zeppelins not planes, no reliable airspeed measurement, no reliable dead reckoning, and the lack of man portable radio systems. If any one full squad of paratroopers all landed on the grounds of Westminster Palace it would be something of a miracle.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises I think your understanding of surrender and peace talks is quite naive. Even if they get the parliament to surrender, the french army would need to accept this surrender. Which they likely won't since they know it was forced by a now hopelessly outnumbered bunch of paratroopers. The would declare the surrender invalid and/or declare a coup and then all you have is wasted a ton of parachutes (which were hella expensive)

Comment: @Cadence I doubt London police in WW1 would be better armed than paratroopers. Some had semi-automatic pistols; others had no guns.

Comment: @user3153372 Which puts them in parity with paratroops who, until they recovered their real weapons from a separate supply drop, would also have handguns or - late in the war - submachine guns.

Comment: Do you think that it was a right wing coup?. It was a left false flag operation.

Answer (score 4):

> What are the minimum historical changes that would permit the use of paratroopers at the beginning of World War I,

This would essentially require aircraft advances to the point of at least 1935-ish - roughly the period large long range transports became available.  Without this you could not lift the men and supplies required, nor could you achhieve the range required.

So that's a minimum of 20 years of aviation advances as well as related advances in engine, supercharging and materials.  A huge requirement.

Note that if you had this you would in any case have used it to dominate the battlefield with airpower, partcularly tactical bombing.

> so that they acomplish the following requisites:

> Ability to take over the British or French parliment.

Neither of these are useful objectives beyond headline grabbing.  You could infiltrate a team to do this covertly and achieve the same result.  All that happens is that the military end up running the country, which is the last thing Germany would want.

> It should be mantained a heavy protected secret of state.

Keeping the development of 20 years of technology secret while building up the resources (planes) and training the men (paratroupers and pilots) is guaranteed to fail.  At the very minimum someone is going to sell enough to your enemies to let them know what you can do (and develop counter-technologies or the same technologies).  Too many people and your entire industry are involved in such an enterprise to keep it secret.  YOu also have to test it all and it will be detected.

> And end the Word War I in less than a week.

Completely impossible the way you want.

Even if you had the technology you could not collapse an entire nation simply by capturing the government.  YOu would need to defeat the military because they would not surrender just because you have a few politicians.

You would still need to link ground forces up with the airborne forces.  Difficult in France, very hard to get across the Channel to the UK but close to impossible to do against the Russians.

You left Russia out of the equations.  Germany's problem was always that Russia, a country with basically unlimited manpower, was going to invade from one side while they tried to take France quickly (before the UK could act).  But Russia is an entirely different prospect to attack than France or the UK. Capturing the Tsar or the Duma would have achieved nothing - Monarchs can be replaced and politicians, well no one in the military at the time liked them anyway.  And as always all the Russians have to do is hold you until winter ...

**How to achieve more ...**

Bombing.

If you can make the transports and do the navigation you bomb Paris and the UK ports - or make it clear you can.  The French might seek a peace if you make a demonstration by causing devastation to e.g. a large French (or Belgian) town, maybe near Paris or a large French city, with a clear offer they might accept (although that would be a very hard thing to find as there was real hatred there).  The UK depends on ports and the more you damage them the less they can send an army.  Likewise air superiority in the British Channel and the ability to sink battleships and troup transports and cargo ships would eliminate the Uk's ability to effectively fight on the continent.

But the French and British would never really surrender.  You'd become an occupying army.  And the Russians, well, that's just going to come back to haunt Germany in any scenario.  Never annoy the Russians in a war. :-)

**And the Peaceful way to dominate ...**

Money.

You've invented all this advanced technology and can easily become the dominant economic power in Europe and end up- basically owning the place.  A queue would form of countries wanting to become economic allies with such a  Germany.  Economic power would equate to political power.  Starting a war is just wasteful.  There's just nothing quite so easy as economic power.

The US would then become the only economic power capable of opposing Germany (economically or politically).  However they could not match the technology and this would actually give Europeans a reasons to *back* Germany's economic dominance, particularly a Europe which was, at that time, ruled largely by related Monarchs.  The UK might be able to remain independant, but it was always a German goal at the start of WW1 to keep the UK out of Europe (militarily) and economic domination of Europe would achieve the same thing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130891/discussion-on-answer-by-stepheng-what-are-the-minimum-historical-changes-that-wo).

Answer (score 4):

In case of Britain, paratroopers would have to capture not only Parliament with all the MP, but also the Royals, as it is the monarch who actually decides such matters in UK. Then maybe they would force a surrender. But highly unlikely with aerial drop.

I'd go for planned-in-advance landing of large force from the river. But in advance I mean before the war: infiltrate a division of troops into London, smuggle in weapons, which would have an upside of getting them heavy weapons and when time comes concentrate them near their targets and execute the grab.

If that's not possible, use Zeppelins to bomb with mustard gas some French city and threaten to do it to Entente capitals and then any larger city if no surrender comes.

Comment: *it is the monarch who actually decides such matters in UK*  The monarch in the UK has practically no real power and is basically there to rubber stamp what parliment recommends.

Comment: @StephenG - Are you sure of that? My own investigation of this merely suggests British monarch ELECTED not to get involved in politics, but all of the traditions are just that - without any support in law. I think any moment they choose they can take back quite a large chunk of power. Anyway, coming back to the topic there's a reason why every law in UK needs Royal Assent, and surrender needs to have a force of law.

Comment: *every law in UK needs Royal Assent* which is a polite way of describing the royal rubber stamp.  I would suggest you try and find a law the UK monarch has refused to sign off on.  Wikipedia claims that [the Scottish Militia Bill of 1708](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Militia_Bill) was the last time a royal "veto" was used.  If you're relying on the UK monarch to prevent insane legislation being passed you're in for a disappointment.

Comment: @StephenG - I know all that. But find me a law that says Royal Assent CAN'T be withheld. That's why I said it's tradition, but it's just that. I assume it's because Royals remember that even a British king can be de-posed by de-capitation, and arguing legality after is moot, unless you know how to re-attach head? From my POV that's 1 for Tradition, but that's not the point in this issue right here?

Comment: @StephenG -- True, though I suspect that if Parliament were captured or otherwise incapacitated, it would be well within King George's right (and indeed his duty) to dissolve Parliament, either with ministerial advice & consent or on his own authority as monarch, and constitute a new, likely interim, government. And if King George was anything, he was dutiful to his country & commonwealth. He would not let a captive Parliament do anything to harm the UK, if it ever came to that.

Comment: @AcePL  *I assume it's because Royals remember that even a British king can be de-posed by de-capitation, and arguing legality after is moot*  There's no possibity that a be-heading could happen and being deposed is nothing more than loosing *part* their cushy lifestyle paid for by the tax payer - loosing one job and getting another one.  A new monarch from the same line of succession would still be in place afterwards.  Thank goodness I'm in a Republic with normal political faults but not that nonsense.  Will the British never cop on ?

Comment: @AcePL Why on earth would you believe that? The British royalty exist solely because they haven't created a reason to get rid of them. Sure, technically they approve it. I'll ask my 10-year-old son what he thinks of the new car I'm going to get too. It doesn't mean my son gets to veto my decision. You need to stop thinking that Disney comedies are documentaries. ;)

Comment: @AcePL I am sure that the tradition of the monarch does no get involved in politics is just a screen to public opinion. because some conversation that King of England had with Teddy.

Comment: @Graham I do not dispute the facts, I just merely point out that legality and tradition are two different thing, when it comes to politics in UK. Skipping insults and ask serious question: do you know what you're talking about or just think you do? Disney talk is funny but also gibberish.

Comment: @StephenG Do I assume you live in dead Republic of USA? If yes, let's examine the tradition and law issue there: 2A says right should not be infringed, but somehow all you can buy is small arms. How is that?

Comment: @AcePL Seriously, I have to ask whether you know what you're talking about. "*I think any moment they choose they can take back quite a large chunk of power.*" Mao said that power comes from the barrel of a gun; but more realistically, power comes from other people allowing them to have that power. As a simple fact, this is not the case in a constitutional monarchy. You're arguing that the royalty can do whatever they want unilaterally, just because tradition hasn't cancelled those laws, and this isn't true.

Comment: @Graham - You quote me saying quite large chunk of power and then say I say they can do anything they want... And that's your only argument, neatly just dismissing mine at the same time. I may be wrong saying tradition hasn't cancelled laws allowing monarchy to reassume power, but you're certainly wrong stating they can't do that. You just think they can't. I have an urge to insert a quote from Inigo Montoya here... Which means EOT for me.

Comment: @AcePL You can both assume anything you like and be wrong.  Both are rights you have.  Oh, wait, according to *you* under a monarchy, people *don't* have rights because a monarch can just dictate what they want to force people to do.  So, again, thank goodness I live in a republic.

Answer (score 3):

Disregarding whether a paratrooper assault would be effective, I looked into whether the technology existed and/or what historically would have to change to support such a tactic.

**Parachutes**

Parachutes were functioning tech at the time.  First used successfully in the late 1700s, by the 1900s they had been developed to use a silk parachute in a prepacked backpack arrangement with a static line to trigger deployment.  They had been perfected to the point that during World War I artillery observers stationed on tethered observation balloons would routinely use them to get down from the balloons.

**Planes**

Airplane development was certainly not to the point to deliver a massed paratrooper assault.  The planes at the time had flight ranges around 100 miles, this limited range would make this infeasible by itself, possibly sea launching from the English Channel could work, but sea planes were still very experimental at the time.  The planes at the start of the war were also almost exclusively single seaters, with almost no cargo capacity, so at best you could get one paratrooper in one plane and have to sacrifice the plane.  Possible weaponized use of the crashing planes aside, this seams unlikely to be able to deliver enough people.  Finally the production numbers, Early World War I models were produced in very low numbers, The dreaded German Fokker E.I. of 1915 only produced 54 planes, similarly only 224 Vickers F.B.5's were built.  By the end of the war the total planes produced were still only numbered in the thousands.

**Zeppelins**

Other answers have discussed Zeppelins as possible but again the capacity makes this extremely unlikely.  Only 70-100 paratroopers per zeppelin would require a massive zeppelin force to deliver the needed troops.

**Ballonkriegers!!**

One crazy possibility, given that the whole idea is a little crazy, let's discuss it: Balloons.  Balloons hit a sweet spot of possible, they have a higher capacity than the small planes of the times, and are much cheaper to produce than zeppelins.
Early balloons in the 18th century used hot air produced by a fire on the ground, hot air balloons of this type were abandoned when Hydrogen and Helium lifting gases were discovered.  Observation balloons using hydrogen were common and mass produced during World War I.  In our world hot air balloon technology (using a onboard heater for the air) wasn't developed until the 1950s, but all of the required base technology for an improved hot air balloons existed before World War I.  Most modern hot air balloons seat 3 to 5 people, but the technology scales and larger balloons exist with capacities as high as 32 people.  Modern balloon festivals are common around the world with number of balloons in the hundreds.

So, given an early German development of improved hot air ballooning this technology could be in play at the start of the war.  Given some larger balloons holding 32 troopers, a mass attack with 500 balloons could deliver 16,000 troops.  Given some luck and good winds these Ballonkriegers could make for a really interesting opening to the war.

[image: BALLOONS]

Image from the Albuquerque International Balloon Fiesta.

Comment: An *entertaining* opening to the war, sure, but then you find yourself with 16,000 troops stuck somewhere with no way to supply them.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of WW1, the only viable aircraft, apart from Zeppelins, would be the [Ilya Muromets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_Ilya_Muromets), a Russian four engined aircraft, used as an airliner (with insulated cabin and the first airborne toilet!) but (mainly) as a bomber, with up to 800kg of bombs, and 9 machine guns including the first tail gunner.

[image]
(for photo credit, see link above)

There were ten of these by the end of 1914, one setting a world record by flying 1200km in 13 hours, stopping only once for fuel. Post war, (no doubt with uprated engines) they demonstrated carrying 60 passengers, but 10 or 15 paratroopers would be more likely in 1914, while also carrying enough fuel for a cross-channel flight to London.

More fundamentally, Russia was on the same side as Britain, so any question of whether 15 paratroopers (or even 150, committing the entire squadron) could duke it out with a handful of startled bobbies in Parliament Square is pretty much academic.